# Run the "action.php" page with an ajaxForm

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Why doesn't it run the "action.php" page? How do I get a PHP page to run?

```php
<form action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <input type="file" name="userfile"  accept="application/pdf">
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('form').ajaxForm({
      uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        //code
      },
      complete: function(xhr) {
        $( "form" ).submit();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to send the form via Ajax _and_ then submit it when it completed the AJAX? That really makes no sense.

Comment: I need ajaxForm for the file upload percentage and I need the php file to upload it to the server.

Comment: The ajaxform should do the upload already. Submitting it again after that is duplication, and defeats the purpose of using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

A Upload File PDF script with Ajax PHP

```
<?php
if ($_FILES) {
    $form_data['errors'] = 'Error Post';
    $form_data['success'] = false;
    if (!empty($_FILES['userfile'] ?? null)) {
        $valid_extensions = array('pdf'); // valid extensions
        $userfile = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $tmp = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
        // get uploaded file's extension
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($userfile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        // check's valid format
        if (in_array($ext, $valid_extensions)) {
            if (!is_dir('upload/')) {
                mkdir('upload/');
            }
            copy($tmp, 'upload/' . $userfile);
            $form_data['success'] = 'Upload successfully !';
            $form_data['path'] = 'upload/' . $userfile;
        } else {
            $form_data['errors'] = 'Invalid File !';
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($form_data);
    die;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>PDF - uploader</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>PDF - uploader</h2>
        <div>By - Didou</div>
        <form id="formUser" action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <input id="formUserFile" type="file" name="userfile" accept="pdf" accept="application/pdf">
            <span id="success"></span>
            <span style="color: red;" id="throw_error"></span>
        </form>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function (e) {
                $("#formUser")[0].reset();
                $("#formUserFile").change(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: new FormData($("#formUser")[0]),
                        contentType: false,
                        cache: false,
                        processData: false,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        beforeSend: function ()
                        {
                            $("#success").fadeOut();
                            $("#throw_error").fadeOut();
                        },
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            if (data.success) {
                                $("#success").html(data.success).fadeIn();
                                $("#formUser")[0].reset();
                                $("#formUser").after('<iframe src="' + data.path + '#toolbar=0" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>');
                            } else {
                                // invalid file format.
                                $("#throw_error").html(data.errors).fadeIn();
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (e)
                        {
                            console.log('err');
                            $("#throw_error").html(e).fadeIn();
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does this answer their question that's about "ajaxForm" (which is a jQuery extension)?

Comment: @magnus-eriksson The script that I wrote uses Ajax Jquery with the Form-Data parameter and then I add PHP to save the file to the server.
sorry I did not comprison your commentair !

Comment: The OP seem to be using a [jQuery Form Plugin](https://jquery-form.github.io/form/) (`$.ajaxForm()`), not the default `$.ajax()` function (since the title specifically mentions "ajaxForm" and then have `$('form').ajaxForm()` in the code).

Comment: @magnus-eriksson yes it's true I did not notice, maybe after I will see with this plugin.